# Swing: How to prohibit interaction outside of JFrame/JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I'd like to show a progressbar and block interaction with my application frame while a thread is being executed.

In another thread someone suggested using JDialog instead of JFrame and `setModal(true)`. However, when doing so the Dialog blocks the entire application.

This is essentially my code:

```
 MyDialog dlg = new MyDialog(); 
 dlg.setModal(true); 
 dlg.setVisible(true); 

 //do some stuff....
 //(never executed when setModal(true)

 dlg.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Make sure that everything is done before realizing the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do it would be using JXLayer and LockableUI.
Look [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2008/07/jxlayer_30_lock.html) for an example of how this can be done.

Also note, that JXLayer made it into Java 7, and is available as [javax.swing.JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayer.html).

The other thing is, that you should not execute long-running tasks insite Event Dispatch Thread. Read about [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and [learn to write multithreaded code for Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Answer (score 3):

That is the point of a modal dialog, no interaction will happen outside the "box". The modal popup also halts the thread while waiting for user input. If you want to do other stuff while showing the dialog you will either have to do it in the dialog itself or start a new thread to take care of it.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

With modal dialog try something like this:

```
                final JDialog dlg = new JDialog();
                dlg.setModal(true);
                dlg.setSize(500, 500);
                dlg.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) { //or other method
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    //execute your long running task
                                } //you should catch exception
                                finally {
                                    dlg.setVisible(false);
                                    dlg.dispose();
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();
                    }
                });
                dlg.setVisible(true);
```

I can also set GlassPane on your JFrame which will intercept any event from the user.